# Exception not caught using Task from Task.Factory.FromAsync()

Tags: asp.net

I have a task created as follows.

```
var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync<Request, Response>(
                service.BeginOp,
                service.EndOp,
                request,
                null);
```

When I await the task in a try/catch, the exception is not caught.

```
try
{
    await task;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Block never reached
}
```

However when I use ContinueWith(), the exception is caught.

```
await task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.Exception != null)
    {
        // Block reached
    }
});
```

Why is it not caught in the first case? I have try/caught other Tasks and it catches the exception.

Comment: Is *anything* after the `await` executed?

Comment: No, nothing after the await executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in the above callstack I was not using await. I am not sure why the compiler allowed this. Adding the await fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that further up your call stack, your code is calling `Task<T>.Result` or `Task.Wait`. This will [cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog.

By default, `await` will capture a "context" whenever it awaits a `Task`. In this case, the "context" is the ASP.NET request context, which only allows one thread in at a time. If your code blocks a thread within that request context (e.g., by calling `Result`/`Wait`), then when the task completes, it cannot resume executing the `async` method because the context only allows one thread in.